# Shiny's progress bar just delays progress

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I used Shiny's withProgress feature for a long calculation: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html

However, it simply puts the system to sleep and I have to wait for the Sys.sleep(xx) to finish before the calculations are actually undertaken. So I don't see the point of using something that makes the calculation process seem twice as long.

Is there some other progress bar approach that doesn't use Sys.sleep(0.25) so that calculations are actually occurring during the progress status display?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not do `Sys.sleep(0.25)` there, that is just an example to make the progress bar work.

If you have a function that has to sum `10.000.000 random numbers 15 times for example, you could do:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                   for (i in 1:15) {
                     incProgress(1/15)
                     sum(runif(10000000,0,1))
                   }
                 })
    plot(cars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Second example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

test_fun <- function()
{
  for (i in 1:15) {
    incProgress(1/15)
    sum(runif(10000000,0,1))
  }
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                      test_fun()
                 })
    plot(cars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. But how can I use it when I call a function that takes 2 minutes. If I use Sys.sleep(xx) to match this time, then it will take 4 minutes before I see the results. Is there a progress option that doesn't put the calculations to sleep so to say?
observeEvent(input$actionButton,{
   
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                   for (i in 1:10) {
                     incProgress(0.1)                     
                   }
                 })
    results = my_function() 
})

Comment: How does the progressbar know when to update in your example? I added a second example which I hope can clarify a bit. You have to call incProgress(0.1) after everytime 10% of your function has completed.

Comment: Oh I see now that's great Florian!. So just to be clear to others with his second example one can distribute the incProgress(0.1) throughout the function in question. Thanks so much for your help on this! I up-ticked your answer but unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points (I'll try again when I do).